# Deleting values of existing pointer array then assigning new values to the pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Is it possible to do the following?

```
 int *n[10];

 for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     n[i] = NULL;
 }

 for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     n[i] = new int(); // and whatever value n[i] is assigned to it
     //
 }

 // then delete again
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     delete n[i];
     n[i] = NULL;
 }
```

Then use the array as if it is fresh using new?

Comment: You can declare and initialize in one line `int *n[10] = { NULL }`

Comment: `int *n[10] =  {}` and skip the NULL initialization loop. And yes, you can do that.

Comment: @SatishChalasani: Only the first element of the array will be initialized with 'NULL' the rest will be initialized with zeros (where NULL and zero are accidentally the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you. As long as you don't leave dangling pointers (`delete n[i]` without reassigning `n[i]`) or cause memory leaks (reassign `n[i]` without `delete n[i]`), there's nothing wrong with your code.

The array `n` you've created is for your use. However you want to use it, you can.